# My JPanel won't show up (Java)

Tags: java, user-interface

I don't understand why my JPanel won't show up since I used pack() and setVisible(true)
It just run the application and nothing happens.
This is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel _panel1 = new JPanel();
    private JTextArea _txtarea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
    private JTextField _txtfield = new JTextField();

    public TestGUI() {
        add(_panel1);
        _panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        _panel1.add(_txtarea);
        _panel1.add(_txtfield);
        validate();
        _panel1.setVisible(true);
        _panel1.setSize(500, 500);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: setVisible() and setSize() belong on the frame, not the panel.  Call them with 'this.' or without anything.  Also, since you set the panel layout to BorderLayout, adding two things to it just overwrites the first thing with the second.  If you want them in different places, you'll have to specify NORTH, EAST, or something -- look up how to use BorderLayout for details.

Comment: You should handle the `windowClosing` event. You wont be able to close the window if you don't. So unless you are going for an undecorated window and implementing a custom close button handling the `windowClosing` event is essential.

Comment: Correction: the window will close but youre program will still run after the window closes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest showing the `JFrame` as well, as it contains your `JPanel`.

Try this as your `main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      new TestGUI().setVisible(true);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues in your code. You are not setting the Layout correctly. **BorderLayout** requires positioning.

Once you have added the components to the JFrame, you either set a size for it or call **pack()** method, so that you JFrame assumes the size needed to fit the subcomponents.

Here is an a sample:

```
class TestGUI extends JFrame {

        private JPanel _panel1 = new JPanel();
        private JTextArea _txtarea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        private JTextField _txtfield = new JTextField();

        public TestGUI() {
            add(_panel1);
            _panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            // border layout is done by positioning like center, south north etc.
            _panel1.add(_txtarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            _panel1.add(_txtfield, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            // set the size before making it visible
            _panel1.setSize(500, 500);
            setVisible(true);

            // call pack() so that the Frame assumes the needed space only
            pack();

            // set a default close method so that your frame  exits on close.
           setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }
```

Next it is a good practice to spawn your JFrame through **SwingUtilities.invokeLater** or **EventQueue.invokeLater** , so that it is handled by the **Event Dispatch Thread** in it's own good  time when processing the queue of events.